# How to display part of an image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm using jquery and I'm trying to display part of an image, say a square in the middle of it, then using animate, roll out the rest of it.

I'm thinking something involving divs, with overflow: hidden, but I can't figure it out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) plugin, it does that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To display the square initially, you would use a technique called **image spriting** and there are many ways to actually accomplish it with CSS.  Here's [one by alistapart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites).  After that, you could use animate to alter the css manually.

However, I bet there's a jquery plugin that does something like this automgaically...

Answer (score 1):

You could setup something similar to a css sprite map where you use css to display a specific part of the image.  Then use jquery to change the css class to something that displays the whole image.

Here's a link about css sprite maps.
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 0):

you have to work with css: position to put a div over another div
[css position](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)